# Potential memory leak with Tensorflow SymbolicTensor created when using Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-leaks

I am working on a TinyML NAS framework, i.e. throughout the execution of my code, hundreds if not thousands of models are created and trained. I am doing this on a Manjaro system running Tensorflow 2.15, Cuda 12.3.52 and Python 3.11.5.

I have come across a problem that has been starving my system of memory after a couple of days of execution. By using `tracemalloc` I have been able to see that the main contributor appears to be the symbolic tensor created when creating a `Conv2D` layer, created at `framework/ops.py:245`. Maybe I am missing something basic in terms of garbage collection in my code but over time the demo code will eventually consume all system memory as can be seen from the first three itterations below, the memory consumption is slowly increasing.

```
Epoch 1/5
...
Top 5 lines
#1: <frozen abc>:123: 1856.2 KiB
#2: python3.11/linecache.py:137: 606.4 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: framework/ops.py:245: 197.9 KiB
    return pywrap_tf_session.PyTensor.__new__(
#4: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:729: 158.6 KiB
#5: framework/ops.py:1211: 137.3 KiB
    self._gradient_function = None
952 other: 1407.6 KiB
Total allocated size: 4364.1 KiB
Epoch 1/5
...
Top 5 lines
#1: <frozen abc>:123: 1846.9 KiB
#2: python3.11/linecache.py:137: 620.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: framework/ops.py:245: 382.3 KiB
    return pywrap_tf_session.PyTensor.__new__(
#4: framework/ops.py:1211: 264.9 KiB
    self._gradient_function = None
#5: framework/ops.py:1161: 254.7 KiB
    self = Operation(c_op, SymbolicTensor)
947 other: 2160.5 KiB
Total allocated size: 5530.0 KiB
Epoch 1/5 
...
Top 5 lines
#1: <frozen abc>:123: 1843.9 KiB
#2: python3.11/linecache.py:137: 620.8 KiB
    lines = fp.readlines()
#3: framework/ops.py:245: 568.5 KiB
    return pywrap_tf_session.PyTensor.__new__(
#4: framework/ops.py:1211: 394.1 KiB
    self._gradient_function = None
#5: framework/ops.py:1161: 378.9 KiB
    self = Operation(c_op, SymbolicTensor)
949 other: 2702.3 KiB
Total allocated size: 6508.5 KiB
```

I have also tried `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` and `gc.collect()` but neither help.

I am not savvy to the backend of Tensorflow and as such would appreciate anyone who can offer me more insight into the problem. Below is a stand-alone demo that replicates the problem.

```
import gc
import tracemalloc, sys, linecache, os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

EPOCHS = 5
BS = 512
TEST_LOOPS = 10000


def start_tracemalloc():
    tracemalloc.start()


def display_top(snapshot, key_type="lineno", limit=5):
    snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces(
        (
            tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"),
            tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<unknown>"),
        )
    )
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics(key_type)

    print("Top %s lines" % limit)
    for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:limit], 1):
        frame = stat.traceback[0]
        # replace "/path/to/module/file.py" with "module/file.py"
        filename = os.sep.join(frame.filename.split(os.sep)[-2:])
        print(
            "#%s: %s:%s: %.1f KiB" % (index, filename, frame.lineno, stat.size / 1024)
        )
        line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
        if line:
            print("    %s" % line)

    other = top_stats[limit:]
    if other:
        size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
        print("%s other: %.1f KiB" % (len(other), size / 1024))
    total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
    print("Total allocated size: %.1f KiB" % (total / 1024))


def display_snapshot():
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    display_top(snapshot)


def create_model() -> keras.models.Model:
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="valid")(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


def train_model(model, train_images, train_labels):
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS)


def main() -> int:
    mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

    train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1], train_images.shape[2], 1)
    train_images = train_images.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

    start_tracemalloc()

    for i in range(TEST_LOOPS):
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
        gc.collect()

        model = create_model()
        train_model(model, train_images, train_labels)
        display_snapshot()
        del model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Thanks in advance